# Using python for data cleaning with pandas after read data from a excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-cleaning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOs7M.png)

You can see in this picture. In the raw data, there are numbers just in the end of some records. They will bring lots of inconveniences for data analysis. Are there any methods or functions to deal with this efficiently no matter how many records are having a 'number' ending.

Plus, read this excel file directly to a pd.Dataframe will be like that and I want to get rid of these numbers('2', '3', '4'...) effectively.

China2

China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region3

China, Macao Special Administrative Region4

Comment: Did you try loading it? Did the numbers remain?

Comment: I use "df=pd.read_excel('file name.xls')". What is the meaning of loading it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete these numbers:

```
df.Country = df.Country.str.replace("\d+$", "")
```

Comment: I have plenty of data files like this. Sometimes there are hundreds of data with a 'number' ending. Thanks! Regular expression is good.

Comment: I have try it, but python always blow up. The most common error message is 'TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index country')'.  I shall describe this in detail. I have excel files with several columns. The firt

Comment: I have try it, but python always blow up. The most common error message is 'TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index country')'.  I shall describe this in detail. I have excel files with several columns. The first column is 'Country'. And in the ending of some country names, there are ‘number' footnote labels('1','2',......'100',...). When I use 'df=pd.read_excel('data.xls'), the country name('China2',etc) will be a whole string. So I want to get rid of these number footnotes after that I can use merge, sort  and other methods to do data analysis.